# How Can I force clear all bluetooth advertising on chrome os

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-chrome-os, eddystone

I am broadcasting Eddystone on chrome os but I can't unregister.

I have tried using `chrome.bluetoothLowEnergy.resetAdvertising` but when I try to advertise after it fails because "An advertisement is already advertising"

I can't even figure out from the docs how to list current advertisements to see if I can get an id to deregister